# Accessing 'this' inside Typescript raw function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I have an Angular 6 app that uses the excellent `ngx-charts` framwork to display charts. This charting component lets me specify a tooltip formatting function like so:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical [xAxisTickFormatting]="dateTickFormatting" >
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

And then define the formatting function in the parent component class:

```
  dateTickFormatting(val: string): string {
    return val.toUpperCase();
  }
```

My problem happens when I try to access values in the parent component class from this formatter function:

```
  public testVar: string = 'This is a test variable';

  dateTickFormatting(val: string): string {
    console.log(this.testVar);
    return val.toUpperCase();
  }
```

In this case, `testVar` will be undefined.

I understand that the 'this' reference is lost because `ngx-charts` is referencing `dateTickFormatting` as a 'raw' function. Is there a way to preserve a reference to the parent classes' `this`, barring modifications to the charting framework?

Comment: Define the callback as an arrow function: `dateTickFormatting = (val: string) => string { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrow functions

If you do

```
  public testVar: string = 'This is a test variable';

  dateTickFormatting = (val: string): string => {
    console.log(this.testVar);
    return val.toUpperCase();
  }
```

It will use the correct this and work.

I recommend reading a bit about arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions